# Android SIP Library with RFC 4353 Support

Tags: android, sip, conferencing

I've been looking at various SIP libraries for Android including the built-in SIP library, PJSIP, MJSIP, doubango, etc. but I haven't been able to find any with RFC 4353 support.

Is anyone aware of a SIP client library that would allow me to create a conference-aware UA on Android?